# PHP Mail Parsing - Exclude a signature

Tags: php, email

I'm developing a support ticket system and decided to implement an email feature. If a ticket is created, the client is emailed with the details.

However, my issue comes with the client responding to this email. How can I strip everything except the main content of the email? I'm not looking for some magical way to know exactly what the body is, some little extras bits are fine if they can't be helped, but what would be the best way to remove as much unnecessary information as possible?

I'd considered finding out how the different email clients format their reply messages and then removing any unnecessary info by having the code detect different strings... e.g. Outlook 2013 does something like this;

```
My reply body.

-----Original Message-----
From: Some Guy [mailto:someguy@example.com] 
Sent: 14 September 2016 5:26 PM
To: 'Ticket System' <tickets@example.com>
Subject: RE: The Ticket [accountid][ticketid:6843]

The original message body.
```

So I'd remove anything below "-----Original Message-----".

Whereas Thunderbird just formats replies like this;

```
My reply body.

On 23/09/2016 5:01 PM, Some Guy wrote:
> The original message body.
```

So I'd have to remove anything below "On xx/xx/xxx x:xx xx, ..." etc. However this method isn't very reliable at all, and especially isn't future proof.

Are there any alternatives you can think of? Otherwise I'll just have to store all of this info into the database unnecessarily.

Comment: Just remember that "Original Message" and "On xx/xx/xxxx" are in English for your sample set, but they can be in *any* language and in *any* format, including not being there at all. Likewise, remember that your respondents may top post, bottom post, or inline post their replies. Since you can't be *certain* where the reply is, I'd suggest storing everything, then *maybe* use a heuristic in your display to ghost out likely original message (which, by the way, you can calculate using `diff`).

Comment: @bishop Very true, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a unique boundary right below your reply body. So your reply-raw-message would always be something like:

```
$unique_boundary = md5(time());

$raw_message = $your_reply . $unique_boundary . $the_rest;
```

Then

```
$explode = explode($unique_boundary, $raw_message);
```

and in your DB:

```
$reply = $explode[0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO email_table (message_content) VALUES ($reply)";
```

Based on user feedback, a solution that would work regardless of where your reply spatially occurs in the message chain:

```
 $raw_message = $start_content . $unique_boundary . $your_reply . $unique_boundary . $the_rest;
```

In this scenario, where your reply is not necessarily at the top of the email chain, your reply always be will be `$explode[1]`.

Comment: A good suggestion, but works only if the respondent top posts, not if he bottom or inline posts.

Comment: How would I split the message up to begin with? E.g. I only have $message, which (most likely) contains the first php generated email (to which the client is replying to) + their inline reply (the only bit I want) being piped to a PHP script (the one I'm working on). Not quite sure how to separate up $your_reply and $the_rest.

Comment: If I understand you (maybe I don't), then you're asking how would you retrieve the random boundary to actually explode on? Can you save the unique boundary in the DB as another field? Otherwise, you can come up with some crazy combo of characters e.g. **xR45_+gH3241!@ww** etc etc. and keep this as your constant boundary, defined in the application or in a config file